# /phpTest/zologize/axa.php? Another botnet?

Tags: logging, botnet

Staring at the log made me think, what is `/phpTest/zologize/axa.php` and why are bots looking for it? Previously, I had lots of `/HNAP1/` requests. Requesting `/HNAP1/` from IPs from log revealed, that all of them were sent by Linksys routers. 3 months later, these requests turned out to be generated by a router worm called TheMoon. But requesting `/phpTest/zologize/axa.php` from these servers returns a 404 error. How these servers got infected, and how can I protect mine from this?

```
124.11.224.69 - - [02/Feb/2014:00:37:16 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "-"
140.113.238.121 - - [21/Feb/2014:01:24:32 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "-"
77.121.132.79 - - [22/Feb/2014:00:03:56 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "-"
142.4.201.210 - - [24/Feb/2014:21:54:33 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "-"
212.83.168.39 - - [24/Feb/2014:23:16:00 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "-"
87.117.229.210 - - [26/Feb/2014:06:34:58 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
78.100.82.99 - - [26/Feb/2014:08:25:48 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
198.50.205.219 - - [26/Feb/2014:09:59:11 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
210.60.142.107 - - [27/Feb/2014:00:12:12 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
101.109.4.73 - - [27/Feb/2014:08:50:46 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
61.91.128.158 - - [27/Feb/2014:08:59:15 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
201.188.41.175 - - [27/Feb/2014:11:25:42 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
220.133.137.2 - - [27/Feb/2014:12:12:46 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
203.156.104.88 - - [28/Feb/2014:18:11:49 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
61.19.52.58 - - [28/Feb/2014:22:02:56 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
84.2.92.40 - - [28/Feb/2014:23:04:17 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "-"
58.64.205.11 - - [01/Mar/2014:06:08:33 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "-"
113.61.200.151 - - [01/Mar/2014:18:25:25 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "-"
178.33.219.12 - - [03/Mar/2014:14:41:48 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "-"
74.63.220.132 - - [04/Mar/2014:01:16:44 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "-"
187.141.230.106 - - [04/Mar/2014:15:39:26 +0100] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "-"
103.22.181.146 - - [09/May/2014:17:16:56 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "-"
176.31.200.14 - - [10/May/2014:19:52:24 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 68 "-" "-"
124.120.92.70 - - [12/May/2014:16:19:40 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 68 "-" "-"
219.85.198.142 - - [15/May/2014:19:21:22 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
80.84.53.226 - - [23/May/2014:08:58:25 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
87.213.11.165 - - [25/May/2014:06:20:27 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
122.116.220.106 - - [25/May/2014:07:10:21 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
58.8.128.30 - - [29/May/2014:02:43:49 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
142.4.197.135 - - [29/May/2014:11:36:45 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
178.32.243.65 - - [30/May/2014:01:59:53 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
58.8.164.221 - - [30/May/2014:14:04:16 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
140.127.182.15 - - [01/Jun/2014:14:45:40 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
218.166.43.21 - - [01/Jun/2014:16:07:52 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
178.32.188.140 - - [01/Jun/2014:19:11:46 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
94.23.211.173 - - [05/Jun/2014:00:52:52 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
120.117.105.201 - - [05/Jun/2014:04:39:39 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
187.172.27.146 - - [05/Jun/2014:10:20:22 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
203.195.219.91 - - [05/Jun/2014:10:53:42 +0200] "GET /phpTest/zologize/axa.php HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 2):

These are just servers scanning your system for a vulnerable script. It happens all the time to any publicly accessible server. Keep your third-party scripts up-to-date.

Comment: I know, but there are more and more IPs, trying to access the same non-existent webpage. No one would waste time and money, to buy 39+ servers in different countries that would only scan for vulnerabilites. It needs to be some worm, and any server with vulnerable software can be easily compromised. As I couldn't find any information about it, I decided to ask about it here, so I'll know, what software should I avoid.

Comment: They don't have to buy them. These are likely infected consumer machines being controlled by a botnet.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote in previous comment :D

Comment: This stuff is normal. Like 100% run of the mill normal. Welcome to the web.